# Does googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo require authentication?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

It seems that when I have a valid user's access token, I can call this api `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=xxx` to retrieve the user info, without any API key.

I want to double check are there any limitation in getting user info via this API, instead of using the official Google API client? e.g. rate limit?

Answer (score 0):

An API key is used to access public information.  Holiday calendars for example or public videos on youtube.   Files uploaded to Google drive set public could also be accessable with an api key.

Oauth2 is used to access private user data, you can access public data with it as well like the items listed above.  But to access private user data like the data contained behind the user info end point you would need an a valid access token.

There shouldnt be any limitations to using the userinfo endpoint that i am aware of I would expect that to be out side of all quota limitations.